# How to create a functor from a list in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm new in Prolog and I try to understand some basic stuff.
Generally, what I am trying to do is to return a functor for a given list.
This example is a relay race and the rules are like:

```
%race(_team,_first_runner,_second_runner)
race(reds,yael,dan).
race(reds,dan,oren).
race(reds,oren,guy).
race(reds,guy,daphna).
race(reds,daphna,tali).
race(blue,yoni,avi).
race(blue,avi,naama).
race(blue,naama,tahel).
race(blue,tahel,tohar).
race(blue,tohar,asaf).

%time(_team,_runner,_time)
time(reds,yael,12).
time(reds,dan,15).
time(reds,oren,12).
time(reds,guy,13).
time(blue,yoni,12).
time(blue,avi,13).
time(blue,naama,15).
time(blue,tahel,8).
time(blue,tohar,10).
time(blue,asaf,20).
```

The wanted predicate should return the teams ranked based on the total time of each group (assume we have `total_time(_race,_total_time)` that returns the total time for a given team).

```
 total_time(team,_total_time):-
 findall(T,time(_team,,T), Times), 
 listsum(_total_time, Times).


 listsum(0, []).
 listsum(Result, [Head|Tail]):-
 listsum(SumOfTail, Tail),
 Result is Head + SumOfTail.
```

For instance:

```
    total_time(reds,T).
    Returns:T=77

    total_time(blue,T).
    Return: T=78
```

So obviously the reds team has finished the race in the shortest time  so they are the winners (1st place) and the blue team -in the 2ed place.

And it should look like that:

```
    rank_teams(_list_o_ranks):- /*The logic that ranks the team and returns
 the result in a data structure of rank(place,team)*/


Input: [reds,blue...]
Output: [rank(1,red),rank(2,blue),…]
```

I have 2 difficulty here, first, is to convert the list of teams to this form:

```
rank(Team, Place):-
rank(Team,Place).
```

The second is to determine the team places (ranking the teams based on thiers time when the shortest is 1st place).

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: No, this is not clear. Try to explain the computation with a complete example, including the data for `blue` and the intermediate steps.

Comment: @Isabelle Newbie Sorry for that, I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still far from complete enough to give a complete, tested answer. But here are some hints.

If you have a `total_time/2` predicate as you describe, you can find the correct order using something like this:

```
ordered_teams(OrderedTeams) :-
    setof(Time-Team, total_time(Team, Time), OrderedTeams).
```

After calling this with your example data, you will have `OrderedTeams = [77-reds, 78-blue]`. The list is automagically sorted by time by `setof/3`.

It remains to number the elements in this list. Here's a sketch:

```
orderedteams_ranked(OrderedTeams, RankedTeams) :-
    orderedteams_ranked(OrderedTeams, 1, RankedTeams).

orderedteams_ranked([], _Rank, []).
orderedteams_ranked([_Time-Team|Os], Rank, [rank(Rank, Team)|Rs]) :-
    Rank1 is Rank + 1,
    orderedteams_ranked(Os, Rank1, Rs).
```

Again, this is not tested.

Comment: `setof/3` doesn't sort automagically, it calls `bagof/3` and then `sort/2` on the result (which is why it removes duplicates, btw). To turn a list like `[a,b,c]` into `[1-a, 2-b, 3-c]` you can use a construct like `findall(N-X, nth1(N, [a,b,c], X), Result)`. Otherwise a good answer (+1).

Comment: The `findall/3` is neat, thanks. And yes, I was aware that `setof/3` producing a sorted result is not *literally* magic...

Comment: I know you know ;-) I guess I was being pedantic. The only reason why I brought it up is because it is through `sort/2` that duplicates are removed.

Comment: First thanks alot for your answer. I'm not sure I understand - how can iterate over the list of teams?Btw, total_time/2 doesn't returns a list so it doesn't works for me.

       total_time(_team,_total_time):-
  findall(T,time(_team,_,T), Times),
  listsum(_total_time, Times).

Comment: `setof` creates a list of solutions from a goal that doesn't generate solutions. According to your description, this should work.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie Maybe I mislead you, total_time/2 produces the total time for a given group (as I wrote above) it actually sum the runners time, if I just call it this way:
total_time(Team,Time) it yields the total time of the entire runners from all the teams combined.
That's why you answer throws exceptions.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie Do you have any idea how to make it works?
I'm still struggling to solve it.

Comment: Add the actual, complete code to the question. The code you added for `total_time/2` cannot be the real code because it is not syntactically correct. Also, please don't use variable names starting with `_` for variables that occur more than once in a clause.